# Jquery if <div> style contains rgb

Tags: jquery, styles, element

I want to check if element's style has rgb. For example

```
<div class="grid" style="background-color: rgba(116, 185, 255, 0.5)">
```

Jquery:

```
if $('.grid') style has rgba {
    //do it
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if it has a color? Or if the color is rgba?

Comment: if the color is **rgba**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>css demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span id="result">&nbsp;</span>
<div style="background-color: blue; color: red">empty</div>
<div style="background-color: rgba(0,1,0,1); color: red"></div>
<div style="background-color:#123456;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#f11;"></div>

<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  var bodyColor = $(this).attr("style");

  if (bodyColor.indexOf('rgba') > -1){
   $( "#result" ).html( "That div <span style='" +
    bodyColor + ";'>has RGBA</span>." );
  }else{
   $( "#result" ).html( "That div <span style='" +
    bodyColor + ";'>does not have RGBA</span>." );
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your snippet works fine. But i dont understand why my code deosn't work good. Can you check it?
https://jsfiddle.net/xcqpF/1554/

Answer (score 1):

Use it :)

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
if(element){
  var style = element.style;
  if(style){
    var color = style.color;//or backgroundColor
    if(color){
      if(color.indexOf(rgba) > -1){
        //Do whatever you want
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in jQuery:

```
if ($(".words").eq(0).css("color").indexOf("rgba") > -1){
  //Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Can you convert it to jquery? I cant integrate to my juqery code.